# Symfony 4.0 TranslatorInterface not autowired in a class

Tags: php, symfony, autowired, symfony4

I use `TranslatorInterface` in a controller with autowiring and it's working properly :

```
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger,
                            TranslatorInterface $translator)
{
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->_translator = $translator;
}
```

However, when I try to use this interface with autowiring in another class, it doesn't work :

```
class MunicipalityValidator
{
    private $_translator;
    private $_validator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator,
                                ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->_translator = $translator;
        $this->_validator = $validator;
    }
    //...
}
```

I have this error message :

```
FatalThrowableError
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Validator\MunicipalityValidator::__construct(),
0 passed in /var/www/html/sf4proj/src/Factory/MunicipalityFactory.php on line 34 and
exactly 2 expected
```

Do you have an idea about the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post how you are using MunicipalityValidator?

Comment: Simply $validator = new MunicipalityValidator();

Comment: That's why it isn't working. You should use it as a service getting it from container or injecting it, or, if you are using that way, you must pass explicitly the objects to the constructor

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean I must create a service for my validator and call this with $this->get('municipality_validator')->myMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3...) ?

Comment: Take a look to the [Custom Constraint Doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.htm) and [Constraint with dependencies](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies)

Comment: You should post the code where you are using the validator, maybe a form builder or in a controller or with annotations in an Entity... i don't know. I mean, add more context.

Comment: I use annotations in an Entity. When my controller is called, he call MunicipalityFactory to create a Municipality object (the Entity).

The MunicipalityFactory call the validator MunicipalityValidator. When errors are detected, the validator throw an exception and I use translator to write a message.

The code is very simply because, currently, it's juste a sample.

Comment: So what you want to do is to inject your MunicipalityValidator into MunicipalityFactory.  And of course you will then need to inject MunicipalityFactory into your controller.  Having your factory also act as a validator might be over doing things a bit.

Comment: In fact, my controller call my factory like this :
    $municipality = MunicipalityFactory::create($insee, $zipCode, $name)

In my MunicipalityFactory, I just want to call a validator and throw an exception if validation fail. In my exception I want to use TranslatorInterface to translate message.

Comment: All I can say is to take a step back and review the examples of dependency injections in the docs.  You are not quite getting the point that everything needs to be defined in the container for this stuff to work.  Static methods are pretty much a no no.  Change MunicipalityFactory::create to $municipalityFactory->create and you will be on the right path.

Comment: And injecting the translator into your validator is another bad idea but not directly related to the problems you are facing.

Comment: Ok thanks.I will do that. One more question: I am not necessarily a fan of static methods, but I find this very useful in the case of a factory. Why do you recommend removing static? Wherever I saw and used factories, it was always static.

Thank you

Comment: Because you can't inject a static method.  If the factory class was completely self contained then by all means use a static method.  But in this case, you need to be able to inject dependencies into the factory and then inject the factory.  Hence no statics.

Comment: Oh yes, but as I will remove the validator, it will be self contained